# Playing Video from Core Data uisng AVPlayer

Tags: swift, core-data, avplayer

I have a video retrieved using `NSData(ContentOf:)` and stored in `CoreData` *(I'm using External storage option in Core Data)*.

now, how can I play it using `AVPlayer` when I fetch it from `CoreData`. I couldn't find a clear answer and I'm a beginner so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea if the way you need to use that data requires a file URL. you should save the videos in the documents directory, and save the names of the videos in Core Data. And for play video retrieve video using video name and then play it.

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docURL = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let path = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myvideo.mp4")

let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path.absoluteString))
let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
vc.player = player

present(vc, animated: true) {
  vc.player?.play()
}
```

Comment: I know this way but I want it directly from Core Data, as I understood from a few articles when using external storage option Core Data do this for you automatically. so do you know how can I do this?